# Is there a way to include a php file asynchronously?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm doing (for the first time) a wordpress based website with heavy content front page.

I would like to load first all the general top content and a couple of seconds later what is known in wordpress as side bars (just includes())

Is there a way to do this with php?

Since the sidebars aren't static I can't just try to do something with ajax or similar.

Thanks

Comment: yeah, with proc_open('php file.php');

Comment: Not in PHP directly. You will need to use JavaScript to make AJAX calls back to WordPress and have it return parts of your site HTML (like sidebars).